# Gradient Descent Step for word2vec negative sampling

Tags: gradient-descent, word-embeddings

For word2vec with negative sampling, the cost function for a single word is the following according to [word2vec](http://www-personal.umich.edu/%7Eronxin/pdf/w2vexp.pdf):
$$
E = - log(\sigma(v_{w_{O}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}})) - \sum_{k=1}^K log(\sigma(-v_{w_{k}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}))
$$

$v_{w_{O}}^{'}$ = hidden->output word vector of the output word

$u_{w_{I}}$ = input->hidden word vector of the output word

$v_{w_{k}}^{'}$ = hidden->output word vector of the negative sampled word

$\sigma$ is the sigmoid function

And taking the derivative with respect to $v_{w_{O}}^{'}.u_{w_{j}}$ is:

$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}} = \sigma(v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}) * (\sigma(v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}) - 1)
$ $ \text{if } w_j = w_O $

$
\frac{\partial E}{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}} = \sigma(v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}) * \sigma(-v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}})
$ $ \text{if } w_j = w_k \text{ for } k = 1\ldots K$

Then we can use chain rule to get

$ \frac{\partial E}{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}} = \frac{\partial E}{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}} * \frac{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}.u_{w_{I}}}{\partial v_{w_{j}}^{'}} $

Is my reasoning and derivative correct? I am still new to ML so any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks good to me. This derivative is also presented in the paper (equations 56-58).

The paper you're linking to is the most advanced attempt - at least to best of my knowledge - to explain how word2vec works, but there is also a lot of other resources on the topic (just search for word2vec on [arxiv.org](http://arxiv.org/find/all/1/all:+word2vec/0/1/0/all/0/1)). If you're interested in word2vec, you may find GloVe interesting too (see: [Linking GloVe with word2vec](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.5595v2.pdf)).

Comment: And the GloVe vectors are significantly faster to compute than word2vec

Comment: Please advise which paper has the equation 56-58. I think the original paper is https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.4546.pdf which does not have 56-58.